# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlite_open() in

Tags: php, html, sqlite

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>List all Contacts - Phonebook</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="phone.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>List all Contacts</h1><br>
  
  <a href="index.php"><strong>Home</strong></a> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <a href="AddContact.php"><strong>Add Contact</strong></a> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <a href="ListAllContacts.php"><strong>List all Contacts</strong></a> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <a href="ListByCategory.php"><strong>List by Category</strong></a> <br>
  
  <br><img src="phone.jpg" /><br><br>
  <?php
    if($db = sqlite_query('phonebook.db',0666, $sqlliteerror))
    {
      $query = sqlite_query($db,"SELECT name,category,number FROM contacts");
      $results = sqlite_fetch_all($query, SQLITE_ASSOC);
      
      foreach($results as $result)
      {
        printf("Contact Name: <em>%s</em> <br>&nbsp&nbsp Relationship category: %s <br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspPhone number <strong>%s</strong> <br />", $result['name'], $result['category'], $result['number']);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      die($sqlliteerror);
    }
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get the following error: PHP Fatal error:  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlite_open() in /home/runner/Yellow-Pages/ListAllContacts.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in /home/runner/Yellow-Pages/ListAllContacts.php on line 16
[Sat Apr  3 07:19:48 2021] 172.18.0.1:35470 [500]: /ListAllContacts.php - Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlite_open() in /home/runner/Yellow-Pages/ListAllContacts.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in /home/runner/Yellow-Pages/ListAllContacts.php on line 16

any recommendations? It works on localhost but not on replit??
Below is me trying to correct it?

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Add Phone Submit - Phonebook</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="phone.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Add to Phone book</h1>
  <a href="index.php"><strong>Home</strong></a> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <a href="AddContact.php"><strong>Add Contact</strong></a> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <a href="ListAllContacts.php"><strong>List all Contacts</strong></a> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <a href="ListByCategory.php"><strong>List by Category</strong></a> <br>
  <br><h2><?php $name = $_GET["name"]; Printf("%s",$name);?> was added as Contact</h2><br>
  <br><img src="gtg.png" /><br><br>
  <?php
    $name = $_GET["name"];
    $category = $_GET["category"];
    $number = $_GET["number"];
    $database = new SQLite3('phonebook.db')
    if($database = SQLite3::open('phonebook.db',0666, $sqlliteerror))
    {
      SQLite3::query($db,"INSERT INTO contacts Values('$name','$category','$number')");
    }
    else
    {
      die($sqlliteerror);
    }
  ?>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This function doesn't exist since PHP 5.5.

Comment: PHP web site only documents [SQLite3](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php). Perhaps you should try that.

Comment: how do i implement? I tried following the guide but it doesnt seem to like it?

Comment: You might want to look into PDO: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: will do i will look at this.

Comment: So I don't believe this applies to me? I am trying to establish a database and it works on personal server but not on replit. I tried to follow the php docs but it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: 172.18.0.1:38934 [500]: /createDatabase.php - Uncaught Error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in /home/runner/Yellow-Pages/createDatabase.php:12
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/runner/Yellow-Pages/createDatabase.php on line 12